# Objective-C can't find Swift protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, migration, swift-protocols

This question is basically the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382652/obj-c-header-file-not-recognizing-protocol-from-swift-class) one, but that one went unanswered.

TL;DR: Protocol does not show up in `MyProject-Swift.h` secret bridging file. And so (not unexpectedly) the Obj-C code can't find it.

I have been able to duplicate it in a from-scratch project. Here is what I did.

1. Create new one-view iOS Objective-C project.
2. Add a new Swift `UIView` subclass via "New File" menu.
3. Confirm that `MyProject-Bridging-Header.h` was created. (Visibly)
4. Confirm that the secret `MyProject-Swift.h` file was automatically created. (Way down there in `DerivedData/.../DerivedSources`).
5. Add an instance of this View to my `ViewController.m`.
6. Include the `MyProject-Swift.h` file in `ViewController.m`.
7. Successfully build -- sanity check

**Now** for the weirdness...

8. Add a Swift protocol file via "New File" menu.
9. Make `ViewController` conform to and implement this protocol.
10. Build fails at this spot in `ViewController.m`:

    `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
    @interface ViewController () <MyProtocol> // Can't find protocol declaration`

Examining the `MyProject-Swift.h` file confirms that the protocol is not in there. But poking around some big pre-existing hybrid projects (that do build) I don't see any protocols in any of *their* `-Swift.h` files.

How do Swift protocols get recognized in Objective-C?

Comment: Following your instruction 1...10, my sample project compiles fine and `MyProtocol` can be found in `MyProject-Swift.h`. Is the protocol really Objective-C compatible? (Having `@objc`?) Have you successfully compiled the protocol's `.swift` file before using it (between your #8 and #9) ?

Comment: Ah `@objc` that did it. I guess in the pre-existing hybrid projects I looked at, the Swift protocols were only used by Swift classes. On a side note, when I launched Xcode this AM and tried to build  (before adding `@objc`) I got the *additional* error of` `-Swift.h` file not found. Even though it did exist. I had this happening sporadically during my debugging of this issue, and it hampered my search a lot. Bug? Anyway, write your suggestion up and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: If `@objc` is the only issue, there are some threads describing it, for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24078242/6541007). And about errors of _`-Swift.h` file not found_, some sort of errors prevent refreshing `-Swift.h`. Comment out all errors as to build successfully, and then uncomment them one by one.

Comment: You are right, I wish I'd found the thread you mentioned. Regarding the file not found, it is not practical to comment out all code that needs it, since I am porting a 700+ file project from Obj-C to Swift. However, doing a Clean Project *and* quitting and restarting Xcode seems to fix things.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this for my project

while defining protocol you can add `@objc` before the protocol definition

```
@objc protocol NewViewControllerDelegate {

}
```

And you are done

Note : I think `@objc` makes swift protocols and classes visible to objective c